# Using react-admin with snowpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin, rollup, snowpack

I want to use `react-admin` in a project with `snowpack` but I encounter the following error

```
✖ snowpack failed to load node_modules/ra-core/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/@testing-library/dom.esm.js
  'default' is not exported by node_modules/@sheerun/mutationobserver-shim/dist/mutationobserver.min.js, imported by node_modules/ra-core/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/@testing-library/dom.esm.js
```

I'm not sure this is a bug of `react-admin` or one of it's dependencies, it might be solvable by changing the config `snowpack.config.json`

Reproduction steps

Initialised a Snowpack project with [Create Snowpack App](https://www.snowpack.dev/#create-snowpack-app-(csa))

```
npx create-snowpack-app new-dir --template @snowpack/app-template-react --use-yarn
```

add package `react-admin`

```
yarn add `react-admin`
```

add the following line in `src/index.jsx`

```
import { Admin } from 'react-admin'
```

run command to start application

```
npm start
```

The there will be a bunch of warnings like:

```
The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten
```

```
Conflicting namespaces: node_modules/ra-core/esm/i18n/index.js re-exports 'TranslationContext' from both node_modules/ra-core/esm/i18n/index.js and node_modules/ra-core/esm/i18n/TranslationContext.js (will be ignored)
Conflicting namespaces: node_modules/ra-core/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/@testing-library/react.esm.js re-exports 'fireEvent' from both node_modules/ra-core/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/@testing-library/react.esm.js and node_modules/ra-core/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/@testing-library/dom.esm.js (will be ignored)
```

```
Warning: 1+ circular dependencies found via "node_modules/ra-core/esm/actions/index.js"
```

Then finally the start script finished with the error

```
✖ snowpack failed to load node_modules/ra-core/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/@testing-library/dom.esm.js
  'default' is not exported by node_modules/@sheerun/mutationobserver-shim/dist/mutationobserver.min.js, imported by node_modules/ra-core/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/@testing-library/dom.esm.js
```

Comment: Looks like a known issue, with the fix to silence those warnings: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/5321